# how to check for properties of GPIO ports

Tags: embedded, gpio

in my blinking LED operation i am using the following functions shown in the code bellow.

when i send a command by UART to turn on an LED i want to know if its turned on or turned off in order to switch its state.

I tried to look in the reference manual for GPIO properties,but this periphery is tricky i cant have  some thing like "LED_PORT_A->STATE"

to see if its turned on or off.

Is there some thing i could do?

Thanks.

https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/EFM32LG-RM.pdf

```
GPIO_PinModeSet(LED_PORT_A,15,gpioModePushPull,0);
GPIO_PinOutSet(LED_PORT_E,15);
GPIO_PinOutClear(LED_PORT_A,15);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current output level you can use `unsigned int GPIO_PinOutGet(GPIO_Port_TypeDef port, unsigned int pin);`

To toggle the current output level you can use `void GPIO_PinOutToggle(GPIO_Port_TypeDef port, unsigned int pin);`.

i.e `GPIO_PinOutToggle(LED_PORT_A,15);`

For more information, the GPIO API documentation for the EFM32-LG is [here](https://docs.silabs.com/mcu/latest/efm32lg/group-GPIO).